# socket.io won't connect from mobile browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to create a web app where players can join a game and their name will be displayed on a main board view. I'm trying to accomplish this with React and Node.js+express using socket.io.

Currently, when a player submits their information, I emit an event to the Node server and their information is pushed to an array of connected users. This array is then returned via API request. My implementation works as expected from desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc) however, I am unable to open a socket.io connection using mobile browsers (in this case, Chrome on Android).

I access my app in both cases by navigating to http://111.111.1.66:3000/ (React-app running on port 3000). I am connected to the same network on all devices and I'm able to see/navigate around my app on all browsers (mobile included).

When a client connects, I log a "user connected" message in the server. I can see this working properly from the desktop browsers but no message is logged when trying to connect on mobile. Similarly, attempting to submit player information from a mobile browser does not emit an event.

Relevant code is as follows:

The client (i.e. the view from which a player submits their information):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import socketClient from 'socket.io-client';

class PlayerJoin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const socket = socketClient('http://localhost:5000');

    this.state = {
      socket,
      name: null,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e, field) => {
    ...collapsed...
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    const { socket, name } this.state;
    const payload = {
      name,
    };

    socket.emit('playerJoin', payload);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <form className="playerForm">
        <input className="nameInput" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'name')} placeholder="Enter name" autoFocus type="text" />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

const users = [];

app.get('/getPlayers', function(req, res){
  res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('playerJoin', (player) => {
    users.push(player);
    socket.broadcast.emit('listUpdate', users); // the main view listens for this event
  });
});

http.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 5000');
});
```

Comment: I hope all your devices are connected to same network. Are they connected to same network?

Comment: Yes, my mobile device is connected to the same wi-fi as the desktops I have been testing on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Change this

```
const socket = socketClient('http://localhost:5000');
```

To

```
const socket = socketClient('http://<ip_of_device_where_your_node_server_is_running>:5000');
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing socketClient('http://localhost:5000'); to socketClient('http://111.111.1.66:5000'); worked!

Comment: Hope you understood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On `client-side` :

```
const socket = socketClient(
   'http://<ip_of_device_where_your_node_server_is_running>:5000'
);
```

You must also modify the server-side too
by replacing the localhost to:
`ip_of_device_where_your_react_server_is_running>:port`

Comment: Running my flask server with `host="0.0.0.0"` did the trick for me. I was running it only on `127.0.0.1`